# how to use java code connection remote hadoop hdfs?

Tags: java, hadoop

I started hadoop at hdfs://*.*.*.* and I can visited *.*.*.*:50070
I want to use java code to CRUD file on remove hdfs.
what should I do?

my java code is

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://*.*.*.*:9000");
    String newDir = "/README.md";
    if (HDFSUtil.exits(conf, newDir)) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
```

Comment: And what is the problem? An exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running on a remote machine, you can try the webhdfs protocol instead of hdfs protocol.